# MySQL query not producing the correct result

Tags: mysql

Given this:

```
MariaDB [master]> describe history;
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| historyid    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| amount       | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| subsidy      | char(1)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_payment | date             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| amount_paid  | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| balance      | float            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| attend       | char(1)          | NO   |     | N       |                |
| attend_date  | date             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| groupid      | int(11) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| clientid     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| memberid     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


MariaDB [master]> describe participation;
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| partid    | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| notes     | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| groupdate | date             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| clientid  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| memberid  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-----------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

MariaDB [master]> select * from participation;
+--------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+
| partid | notes     | groupdate  | clientid | memberid |
+--------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+
|    194 | test test | 2016-01-26 |        3 |        1 |
+--------+-----------+------------+----------+----------+
```

How do I write the following query

```
MariaDB [master]> SELECT attend_date, groupdate, h.clientid, h.memberid
-> FROM history AS h
-> LEFT JOIN participation AS p ON groupdate = attend_date
-> WHERE h.memberid = "1"
-> AND MONTH(attend_date) = "1"
-> AND YEAR(attend_date) = "2016"
-> AND attend_date <> "0000-00-00"
-> ORDER BY attend_date ASC;
+-------------+------------+----------+----------+
| attend_date | groupdate  | clientid | memberid |
+-------------+------------+----------+----------+
| 2016-01-26  | 2016-01-26 |        3 |        1 |
| 2016-01-26  | 2016-01-26 |        4 |        1 |
| 2016-01-26  | 2016-01-26 |        1 |        1 |
| 2016-01-26  | 2016-01-26 |        2 |        1 |
| 2016-01-28  | NULL       |        3 |        1 |
| 2016-01-28  | NULL       |        4 |        1 |
| 2016-01-28  | NULL       |        1 |        1 |
| 2016-01-28  | NULL       |        2 |        1 |
+-------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

so that my return is like this

```
+-------------+------------+----------+----------+
| attend_date | groupdate  | clientid | memberid |
+-------------+------------+----------+----------+
| 2016-01-26  | 2016-01-26 |        3 |        1 |
| 2016-01-26  | NULL       |        4 |        1 |
| 2016-01-26  | NULL       |        1 |        1 |
| 2016-01-26  | NULL       |        2 |        1 |
| 2016-01-28  | NULL       |        3 |        1 |
| 2016-01-28  | NULL       |        4 |        1 |
| 2016-01-28  | NULL       |        1 |        1 |
| 2016-01-28  | NULL       |        2 |        1 |
+-------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

The whole idea here is to be able to pull **all** the clients who don't yet have `notes` applied to a `groupdate` matching `history table's` `attend_date`. And only when a note is posted will the `groupdate` be set to the `attend_date`. Yet, the query, as I have it , returns a `groupdate` of `2016-01-26` for all four `clients` instead of just the one. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you post a sample from the `history` table? It looks like you may need another condition `AND h.clientid = p.clientid` in the join's `ON` clause.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - Post that as an answer, Michael. That's what it needed. I didn't know that I cld place multiple conditions to the `ON` clause. I guess I need to get out more often. Thank you.

Comment: Did you also need `AND h.memberid = p.memberid`? It isn't clear to me if that is necessary.

Comment: It's unnecessary. My query as you see it has the memberid, month, and year hard coded. I use PDO though. So those are all checked against variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your table structure, I see the relationship between your `attend_date` and `groupdate` on which you attempted to join, but I also see that those tables have `clientid` and `memberid` in common.

Since you only joined on the date, you're getting back a cartesian product of all clients and all dates for that condition. You can make the join's `ON` clause more specific by adding additional conditions with a logical `AND`.

```
LEFT JOIN participation AS p
  ON groupdate = attend_date
  AND h.clientid = p.clientid
```

It isn't fully obvious to me if your desired result set also requires a condition to match `memberid` between those tables, but if it does, the solution is as simple as another `AND`.

```
LEFT JOIN participation AS p
  ON groupdate = attend_date
  AND h.memberid = p.memberid
```

It helps not to think of a join's `ON` clause as merely a match between common columns, though that's the most common way it is used. Instead the `ON` clause just needs to present some condition that when true results in a joined row being returned (just like you're used to with a `WHERE` clause). That means you can place just about anything there which can be evaluated as true or false, allowing for complex joining logic.  And the same can be said for `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Since the member will have many clients, only the clientid needs to be checked. By checking the memberid in the `WHERE` clause, only the clients under that member will be returned. And again, I appreciate your insight. You've taught me something today. Thanks.